# Python adding up the length of lists of number

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sum, frequency

So i am trying to find a specific word in txt file, and add up its occurrence, the code I used

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\bshall\b")
pattern1 = re.compile(r"\bmay not\b")
pattern2 = re.compile(r"\bmust\b")

with open('C:\Python27\projects\Alabama\New folder\\4.txt', 'r') as myfile:
 for line in myfile:
    m = re.findall(pattern, line)
    #m1 = re.findall(pattern1, line)
    #m2 =  re.findall(pattern2,line)

    k = len(m)
    #k1 = len(m1)
    #k2 = len(m2)
    #sumk = sum(len(k) for k in myfile)
    print k
```

when I print out k, it gives a vertical list of number of [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2........]
I can tell that these are the number of occurrence of the string "shall" in each line of the text, my question is how to do I add up these list of numbers to get the sum/total occurrence of "shall" in the whole text file.

Comment: k = len(m)+k  , Define k outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a running total:

```
total = 0
for line in myfile:
    m = re.findall(pattern, line)
    total += len(m)

print total
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to `sum` a list, you could use `sum`, but you need to define `k` outside such that it won't be *replaced* with new value every time:

```
k = [] #define k as empty list here
for line in myfile:
    m = re.findall(pattern, line)
    k.append(len(m)) #append the list with new item
val = sum(k) #get the sum here
```